# CLR Trigger throwing exception when insert/update the table

Tags: c#

I would thank first to help me for my earlier issues with CLR Trigger,now it got deployed and am trying to start test,it throws error when am insert or update the record and it terminates.

```
Error:

Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure WCFTrigger, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'WCFTrigger': 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Triggers' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' registered for extension 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' could not be loaded. (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config line 185)
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfi...
The statement has been terminated.



The trigger created in my table :

CREATE TRIGGER [WCFTrigger] ON [dbo].[tbCR]  AFTER  INSERT, UPDATE AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [ServiceClient].[Triggers].[Trigger1]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'SqlAssemblyFile', @value=N'WCFTrigger.cs' ,@level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'tbCR', @level2type=N'TRIGGER', @level2name=N'WCFTrigger'

GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'SqlAssemblyFileLine', @value=N'55' ,@level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'tbCR', @level2type=N'TRIGGER', @level2name=N'WCFTrigger'
```

Please some one throw me a light what am missing here.Am running on VS 2010 but target Frame work is 3.0.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does the config file look like located at this path in your error message C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config line 185 also is there a v3.0 or 3.5 folder under the c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework...??

Comment: Line 185 in the config file its one line i just add newspace here to read <commonBehaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior/>
</endpointBehaviors><serviceBehaviors>
<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior/>
</serviceBehaviors>
</commonBehaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

Comment: yep i do have V1,V2,V3,V3.5 and V4 folder under the Framework file path

Comment: I noticed another thing in my SQL assembly some of the assembly version says 2.0 and some of them are 3.0,look like is screwed up with some versioning problem here

Comment: are you doing your project as a 3.5 or 4.0 the versioning shouldn't matter from that point as long as the assemblies that you are referencing are truly of that ver / framework if you can follow what I am saying.

Comment: Am doing in ver4.0 but changed the target framework to version 3.0.And i can see all the assemblies in that framework folder.If suppose not there then when i was create assembly it should thrown error right ?

Comment: .NET 4.0 has it's own separate GAC not many are aware of that.. 2.0 / 3.5 can share the same becasue under the hood 3.0/3.5 is really 2.0 with some added extensions

Answer (score 0):

Run that: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\vsdiag_regwcf.exe -u` and than restart the sql instance ervice